# Filemaker Value List by calculation?

Tags: list, relationship, filemaker

I want to have about 8 different Value Lists from a field called "ProfileName" for separate dropdown list purposes depending on certain values in a Position or type field.  It seems the only way I can accomplish this is by having 8 separate relations just for this purpose, and while it would be nice to do this based on calculation, is there perhaps a cleaner way to do this without having so many extra relations?

For example:
    where Position = "Project Mgr", get all names associated
    where Type = "O", get all names associated
    where Position = "Supervisor", get all names associated

Comment: A description of the tables involved would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the only way I can accomplish this is by having 8 separate
>   relations just for this purpose

One relationship should be quite sufficient. Your description is not quite clear but as an example, if you have a Position field and a relationship based on matching Position, then once you enter "Supervisor" into the Position field, a value list showing only related values will show only supervisors.

***Added:***

It seems like you have a structural problem: instead of 8 position fields, you should have 8 (or any number of) position **records** in another table. Your current predicament is merely a symptom of the structural issue.

Here's an example of something which I *think* is similar to what you describe:

[image]

Here, your project would have 8 related records in the Roles table. In each role record, you would select the RequiredType and then assign a staff member to the role using a value list defined to use values from EligibleStaff::StaffID, show only related values starting from Roles.

Comment: My Profiles table may look like as follows:

Position = "Alternate Contact", Type = "O", ProfileName = "Abe Aaron"

Position = "Alternate Contact", Type = "A", ProfileName = "Adam Allen"

Position = "Building Supervisor", Type = "A", ProfileName = "Arnold Adams"

There may be 8 different positions I want dropdowns for in another layout (ie. "Building Supervisor", "Project Mgr", etc...) or all those in an O type group for Other contacts only in a separate dropdown.

Comment: @jfalberg Please add this clarification to your question - and add more details abut what your solution is designed to track.

Comment: I was trying to add this in html table format but kept getting red error messages which I didn't understand,

Comment: There was one other method that seemed to work so far:

make a calculation field off of my intended goal and made it a value list:
ProfileOther - Calculation Text, Case(PersonType="O";ProfileName; "")

Comment: @jfalberg That's not a good method because (a) you will need 8 such calculation fields and 8 value lists; and (b) it will not solve your structural weakness which will cause you further problems down the road.